# Running a Python script for the first time. Using terminal to see output?

Tags: python, parsing, terminal, beautifulsoup

I'm following a tutorial on creating a chlerograph map using python.

The tutorial is here: http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/

Following the instructions I have created a directory with:

1. An svg xml map
2. A csv file with data
3. A python script "colorize_svg.py" with cut and pasted code from the tutorial.
4. A downloaded script library folder called "beautiful soup" (actual folder name "beautifulsoup4-4.1.3")

Everything seems straight forward enough, even if I have little coding experience and none with Python. Except step 14 "Now all we have to do is run our script and save the output" The author is referring to the terminal on the Mac. In any coding I have done previously it's always been a case of opening a file, say an html file, with a browser to see the output.

This threw me off. How do I see my output using the terminal? Never used the terminal before? Must I somehow "link" the terminal to the "colorize.py" file? How? I tried just entering the files path into the terminal and hitting enter but got the attached image[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just run it with the python command:

`python /users/gcameron/Desktop/map/colorize_svg.py`

If you just run `python` it will open the python console where you are able to run python code. This is good for testing small things, functions and similar stuff. Mostly I use it as a calculator though.

In your python script, you can also define that it is a python script by (at the top of the document) type `#! /bin/python`. Or if you have python installed elsewhere just type `#! /path/to/python`. If you do this, you just need to execute type the path to the script: `/users/gcameron/Desktop/map/colorize_svg.py` and it will execute the python script with the python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

Before pointing you in the right direction I must advocate you to take 30 minutes to learn the basics of python, [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/index.html) is a great resource (first chapters). Once you get familiar with the ways you can run Python programs and the Python Interpreter itself, it will make sense running your script with the command:

```
python /users/gcameron/Desktop/map/colorize_svg.py
```

Additionally, the interpreter gave you (a not very nice, ok) hint, that something went wrong with the command you tried to execute: it had an invalid syntax.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at this tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You actually can run your script from inside the interactive interpreter (which is what you get when you run `python` instead of running a script from the terminal as `python scriptname.py`).

First, `cd` to the directory containing your script, then type `execfile("scriptname.py")` at the `>>>` prompt in the interactive python environment. (note quotation marks!)

Another way to see- and further manipulate- contents of your script after execution is to use IDLE, a basic python IDE that may not come with the version of python that Mac OS X includes by default. If you installed your own version of python (say from python.org in an effort to be more up-to-date), then you can run your script from within IDLE, and all variables etc will be available in a console window afterwards.